# stacked 3d polygon chart in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

'I am trying to create a stacked area chart like belowfrom this data.  does anyone know how I can take this data and convert it to this type of chart? I am trying to get column headers as z, x as date and y as number of tweets

'!wget -nc https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/ml-files-distro/v1/bloomberg-tweet-topics/data/tweets-categorized.csv -P data
'

I have looked at the matplotlib documentation but it seems to be above me. this is how the data looks like though.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/polys3d.html

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/ml-files-distro/v1/bloomberg-tweet-topics/data/tweets-categorized.csv')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

harris = df[df.username == 'KamalaHarris'].resample('8D', on = 'date').sum()
# Make a list of dates between the first and last 
first = harris.index.min()
last = harris.index.max()

# Go between the first and the last in 2-day chunks
frequency = pd.date_range(start=first, end=last, freq='2D')
smooth = harris.reindex(frequency)

# Plan out 2-day chunks between the first and last days
first = harris.index.min()
last = harris.index.max()
frequency = pd.date_range(start=first, end=last, freq='2D')

# Inject the new (empty) rows, then interpolate new data
smoothed = harris.reindex(frequency).interpolate(method='quadratic') # Data I want to use in stacked polygon chart
```

[Layered Area Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq5Z8.jpg)